# Is a Catholic marriage valid if one or both spouses are in a state of mortal sin at the wedding?

Tags: catholicism, sin, marriage, morality

Suppose Alice and Bob are both Catholics, and they are getting married. If one of them has committed a mortal sin and has not been to Confession at the time of the wedding, is their marriage valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canon law, [book IV, title VII, chapter III](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann998-1165_en.html#CHAPTER%20III.) gives all specific reasons why a marriage would be invalid. Mortal sin is not one of them.

Comment: It's valid but not licit.